# Video Splash Not Showing On Mobile

Tags: wordpress, video, splash-screen, storefront

I have a video on this website: https://remoobledev.wpengine.com/products/whiteboard-renew/ 
On desktop the video loads fine with a preview of the video. On mobile however there isn't a splash and it just shows a "play" arrow which isn't intuitive and doesn't really give an impression of what the video is about. This is within the Storefront theme > Product > Product Video.

Does anyone know how to add a splash image?
Here's an image of the example. https://snag.gy/LboEdF.jpg

Thanks in advance.